# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)?

Tags: php, magento2.4.3

I installed Magento 2.4.3 in ubuntu,
but when I run the below command it gave me errors like,

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: NO)

**Command:**

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/m243"
> --db-host="localhost" --db-name="m243" --db-user="root"
> --db-password="test@!123" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port="9200"

but when I login into PHPMyAdmin using the same id password of the database

> user name: root, password: test@!123

it was worked but did not work in the terminal when I run the command.

please help me with this.

Comment: Confirm that Magento install directory is named m243 and it's not just your database name ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the host as 127.0.0.1 and not localhost as technically they are different

Answer (score 0):

If the database is created and the issue still persists then try the command like this i.e. without the quotes ".

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost 
--db-name=magento 
--db-user=magento 
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento
--admin-lastname=User 
--admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin 
--admin-password=admin123 
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD 
--timezone=America/Chicago 
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 
--elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to the MariaDB/MySQL shell using the mysql command below.

mysql -u root -p

Now create a new database for Magento installation. Create the database 'magentodbatabase' and the user 'magentodatabaseuser' with the password 'magentodbpassword'.

2. Run the MySQL queries below.

   create database magentodbatabase;

   create user magentodatabaseuser@'localhost' identified by 'magentodbpassword';

   grant all privileges on magentodbatabase.* to magentodatabaseuser@'localhost';

   flush privileges;
3. Now type 'exit' to log out from the MySQL shell.

Answer (score 0):

if you have created a virtual host..try this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/m243" --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="m243" --db-user="root" --db-password="test@!123" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port="9200"
```

if you haven't created a virtual host and running it locally your base url would be changed..try below command for localhost:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/m243/pub" --db-host="127.0.0.1" --db-name="m243" --db-user="root" --db-password="test@!123" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port="9200"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the password contains any special characters, then we need to escape them by adding a backslash before the special characters. Below is an example using the password **test@!123**. This will help resolve the "Access denied" problem when you have already attempted to use valid credentials but they are not working.

```
--db-password="test\@!123"
```